# Concrete Roman operator names

Tags: fonts, math-operators, math-fonts

Using [any of the Concrete Roman packages](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-concrete) together with `eulervm` seems to produce operator names such as `\sin` and `\cos` being typeset with a bitmap font. How can I have these rendered with a vector font, same as the text?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ccfonts}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}

\begin{document}
Concrete Roman can write sin and cos in text, but not in math:
\begin{equation}
    \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should load `eulervm` after `fontenc`.

Comment: Well that was easy. Care to write an answer?

Comment: I was trying to see where I got the package order from originally, and curiously both "The LaTeX Font Catalogue" and "A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX" load the packages in the wrong order!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple to do after the nice comments. Here there is the complete solution whete you not see `\sin` and `\cos` being typeset with a bitmap font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
Concrete Roman can write sin and cos in text, but not in math:
\begin{equation}
    \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```